# VBA runs fine in Excel, but throws error 1004 in Visual Basic Form?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro-Enabled workbook with some macros, then I used Visual Studio to create a form in which I use this:

```
Private Sub GenerateBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GenerateBtn.Click
    APP.Run("'CAT-prueba-de-macros.xlsm'!CrearListaCarreras")
End Sub
```

When I run the macro in Excel it works fine, but when I use `APP.Run`, an Excel error comes up saying

> "Error 1004: copy area and paste area are not the same size and shape"

in this part of the macro:

```
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B1").Select
**Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True**
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to using `Select` in your VBA and also using `Range` without specifying its sheet, I suggest you this code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Copy
ws.Range("B1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
ws.Range("A:A").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Comment: I try changing that code in the macro and have the same problem. When run from Excel it works, but when I call the macro from Visual Studio it doesn't work.

Comment: "Error 1004: copy area and paste area are not the same size and shape"